# Capacitor, android onActivityResult inside plugin

Tags: java, android, capacitor

I struggle to understand `context` `activity` inside Capacitor plugin.

Inside one of the plugin methods,
( I stripped the code just to show the problem)

```java
public class GooglePayPlugin extends Plugin {
    private Activity activity;

    public void init(PluginCall call){
        activity = getActivity();
        googlePayClient.requestPayment(activity, googlePayRequest, (success, error) -> {
          if (error != null) {
            // handle error
           }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        googlePayClient.onActivityResult(resultCode, data, (paymentMethodNonce, error) -> {
        // send paymentMethodNonce.getString() to your server
    });
  }
}
```

How to get activity,  that will call `onActivityResult` inside the plugin ?
In example above I get `onActivityResult` response, but it's inside `MainActivity` so I don't have access to plugin properties.